# Does the Stack Exchange owner have a user account?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, users, joel-spolsky

Just a curious question, does he/she actually use this site or any of the sub topic sites?

If so, where is his/her account?

Comment: Do you mean the [two](https://blog.codinghorror.com/about-me/) [founders](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes.

Joel Spolsky who is the founder and current owner of Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange has active accounts on many Stack Exchange sites, for example his [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky), with 183 answers and 12 questions.

His most recent call for help (i.e. asking a question) was [Using Serial Plotter with Visual Studio Code](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/57572/using-serial-plotter-with-visual-studio-code), on the Arduino site.

Comment: There were two founders. Isn't [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) still an owner?

Comment: @Peter no, Jeff quit the company few years ago and no longer has any share or influence on it.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes.

The two co-founders, Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky, both have accounts here.

Adding to Shadow Wizard's answer, [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood), the other co-founder, also has an account with high records. However, he has left the company long ago and is no longer active, nor does he own the company anymore.

Comment: Well, from what I understand "owner" is someone who currently owns the company. :)